# Swift version of Obj.C macro : IS_RETINA

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I used this code:

```
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```

I need swift code for above macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a global constant for that:

```
let isRetina = UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector("displayLinkWithTarget:selector:") && UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Define this out of a `class` bracket

```
let IS_RETINA = UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector(Selector("displayLinkWithTarget:selector:")) && UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 2.0
```